# CORS errors in next13 app with Strapi backend (axios for http requests)

Tags: http, axios, cors, strapi, next.js13

I'm encountering a problem in my next13 app, and I'm having trouble finding the root of it.
The following error is thrown in my console (client):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:3000/src/app/api/auth/user. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.
```

I've looked that up and understand that it's a headers issue with my http requests, where I don't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000` header in my http request, but my issue is that I've tried every method I could find to solve the issue, to no avail. I've tried middleware, I've tried adding the headers object with the exact header in every single http request, nothing has worked. I'm not very familiar with axios so I'm not sure if the issue lies with how I'm handling the issue using axios, or if it's some Route Handlers issue with my next code..

Here's the code on the Page I'm rendering that is calling for the http request:

*/src/app/login/page.js*

```js
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';

import useRouter from 'next/navigation';
import { UserContext } from '../../context/user';

import LoginForm from '../../components/LoginForm';

function Login() {
    const { user, jwt, setUser, checkLogin } = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function checkLoginFunction() {
            const res = await checkLogin();
            // console.log(res)
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setUser(res.data);
            }
        }
        checkLoginFunction();
    }, []);
    if (user) {
        useRouter.push('/user');
    }
    return <LoginForm />;
}

export default Login;
```

*/src/app/login/layout.js*

```js
import '../globals.css'
// import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import UserProvider from '../../context/user'

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'null',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
          <html lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">
              <head>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
              </head>
              <body className={"bg-body-tertiary"}>{children}</body>
          </html>
    </UserProvider>
  )
}
```

Here's the code for the functions called:

*/src/context/user.js*

```js
"use client"

import { useState, createContext } from 'react';
export const UserContext = createContext(null);
import { linstance } from '../lib/api';

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {

    // value inits
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [id, setId] = useState();
    const [jwt, setJwt] = useState();
    const [loggingIn, setLoggingIn] = useState(false);

    // functions
    const doLogout = async () => {
        const resp = await linstance.post('/src/app/api/auth/logout', {
            method: 'POST',
        });
        if (resp.data.message == 'success') {
            setUser('');
            setEmail('');
            setId('');
            // router.push('/user/login');
        }
    };

    async function checkLogin() {
        try {
            const resp = await linstance.get('/src/app/api/auth/user');
            setUser(resp.data.user);
            setEmail(resp.data.email);
            setId(resp.data.id);
            return resp;
        } catch (error) {
            return error.response;
        }
    }

    async function doLogin(values) {
        var ret = ['niente'];
        try {
            const resp = await linstance.post('/src/app/api/auth/login', values);
            return resp.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return ['alert', error.response.data.message];
        }
    }

    const useract = {
        user: user,
        setUser: setUser,
        loggingIn: loggingIn,
        doLogout: doLogout,
        doLogin: doLogin,
        setLoggingIn: setLoggingIn,
        checkLogin: checkLogin,
        jwt: jwt,
        setJwt: setJwt,
        email: email,
        setEmail: setEmail,
        id: id,
        setId: setId,
    };

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={useract}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default UserProvider;
```

and here's the code for the api (here for `\login`, there also are `\logout` and `\user`) (Note I'm using the **App Router**, not the Pages Router - just in case)
*/src/app/api/auth/login/route.js*

```js
import axios from '../../../../lib/api';
import cookie from 'cookie';
export async function POST (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var resp = {};
        resp = await axios
            .post('api/auth/local', req.body)
            .then((response) => {
                const jwt = response.data.jwt;
                const id = response.data.user.id;
                    return new Response(
                        res
                            .setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
                                cookie.serialize('token', jwt, {
                                    httpOnly: true,
                                    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
                                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
                                    sameSite: 'strict',
                                    path: '/',
                                }),
                                cookie.serialize('userid', id, {
                                    httpOnly: true,
                                    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
                                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
                                    sameSite: 'strict',
                                    path: '/',
                                }),
                            ])
                            .json({ message: response.data.user })
                    );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (!error.response.data.error.message) {
                    return new Response(res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' }));
                } else {
                    const messages = error.response.data.error.message;
                    return new Response(res.status(403).json({ message: messages }));
                }
            });
    }
};
```

Currently I still have middleware in the app, though they don't seem to do anything

*/src/middleware.js*

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request) {
    // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
    requestHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000')

    // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
    const response = NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            // New request headers
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    })
}
```

I apologize for the length of the post, but I wanted to be as detailed as I could! Any and all help would be tremendously appreciated!

I've tried to add headers to the axios request

```js
.post('api/auth/local', req.body, {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  },
})
```

I've also tried using middleware as described and shown in the main post's body, I've tried to change the next.config.js headers configuration to add the CORS headers there, I expected at least one to go through and to get anything else other than a 404 error with the same CORS message, but I've only seen that one CORS message (along with an error about a property being undefined because i didn't receive the expected 200 response from the GET request.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically CORS is ignored by Strapi when running in local.  I wonder what would happen if you would remove the middleware.

And see if that changes anything.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request) {
    // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
    requestHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000')

    // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
    const response = NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            // New request headers
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    })
}
```

I am using next js my project and don't seem to have CORS issues. Here is the example when I am making API call to my Strapi APP.

```
xport async function fetchAPI(
  path: string,
  urlParamsObject = {},
  options = {}
) {
  try {
    // Merge default and user options
    const mergedOptions = {
      next: { revalidate: 60 },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      ...options,
    };

    // Build request URL
    const queryString = qs.stringify(urlParamsObject);
    const requestUrl = `${getStrapiURL(
      `/api${path}${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ""}`
    )}`;

    // Trigger API call
    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, mergedOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error(`Please check if your server is running and you set all the required tokens.`);
  }
}
```